# ASP.NET 4.0 - Remove index.aspx from url / Duplicate content?

Tags: asp.net, redirect, duplicate-content

I have a big problem on my website (ASP.NET 4.0 with SSL Certificate) 3 months ago.

The thing is when the user try to access using www - the website refirect to https://xxxx.es

However when the user try to access to the website without www - it redirect to https://xxxx.es/index.aspx

Google says that it is duplicatr content.

I need to remove the index.aspx in the second case or redirect to the index.aspx in the first case. I prefer remove index.aspx ...

I have tried to resolve the problem in many different ways:
- Using Plesk
- Using web.config - creating rules
- Using Redirect
- Using Google Wemaster Tools - They say that the configuration is ok

But any of them solve my problem.

I hope you can help me.

Thanks. :)

Comment: Check on how you configured your redirects - the 2nd option which is your actual target shouldn't have to redirect. As a side note, the whole notion of "duplicate content" being "bad" is more along the lines of "spam" - [real duplicate/unhelpful/no added value content - which in your case isn't](https://youtu.be/mQZY7EmjbMA)

Comment: Thanks mate for your answer... but I don't understand very well. I have watched the video but I can't find a solution to my problem. How can I do to redirect from https://xxxx.es to https://xxxx.es/index or the contrary?

Comment: The video is specific only to "duplicate content" (unless it's really duplicate, Google is ok with it). For your redirect issue (technical part of your question), as above, check your code and/or settings that handle/respond with the redirect. Nobody here can guess what settings you have in IIS, redirect settings, code level redirects, and even DNS/domain level redirects/"forwarding"....